# Linux monitoring tool

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, monitor, bandwidth

My company has quite a few websites hosted on a AWS EC2 instance, each of the websites is in a EBS volume attached to the instance. All the websites have the same public ip, just domain name is different.

So my question is is there any tool that can generate report for each website, for certain time and how many users visited. I can't change the source code, so I guess I can't use Google Analytics, the tool has to read from the log file to generate the report?

It's running on linux. It doesn't matter if it is a web GUI version or a console version.

I've tried Munin and Nagios, I don't think they do exactly what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for free opensource solution than [AWStats](http://www.awstats.org/) and [Webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) are good tools. And if you want Enterprise Solution than [SimilarWeb](http://www.similarweb.com/) is the tool. It got a lot more detail and it’s more accurate.

Comment: I knew there would be something like that! Thanks very much Sid!

Answer (score 0):

I've used AWStats for this in the past (awstats.org).

Comment: Thank you! I will go with AWStats :)